# Bluetooth/Wi-Fi Troubleshooting: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Intel AX200

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, iwlwifi, additional-drivers

I'm a new user to Ubuntu, but a novice/moderate experienced Linux user. I am getting strange Bluetooth behavior, and I found out my new hardware is Intel chipset that is both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. However, under Additional Drivers in Software and Updates, the problem only shows up as my Wi-Fi.

[image: Additional Drivers in Software and Updates]

The driver backport is completely blacked out. That backport should have fixed the issue, especially since the kernel has compatibility with this Intel chipset.

Also, the Wi-Fi is working fine. Bandwidth tests show it is working at full speed.

Ideas how to troubleshoot from the command line to manually use the driver backport?

Comment: The backports-iwlwifi-dkms is for wifi only, the bluetooth is controlled by different drivers

Comment: That makes sense. Since the bluetooth and Wi-Fi run off the same chipset, is the root cause a driver conflict? Do you recommend a manual install of a different bluetooth driver?

Comment: @PsyOne I have the same issue in Additional Drivers selection. The wifi worked without problems for two days, then after turning on the laptop on the third, I get "wifi adapter not found" problem. Did you manage to find a way to manually force usage of that driver or at least reinstall it?

Comment: I had the same thing on my Laptop, everything was working fine with bluetoth and wifi, but I installed kernel 5.7 just to try something if it works and then reverted back to the 5.4 kernel, after that this was not available in Additional Drivers anymore..

Answer (score 7):

Sorry this is not an answer on how to debug bluetooth, but I cannot post comments yet, so I'm giving you these information here.

Intel AX200 is having major problems with linux (for instance, i have the same card and sometimes, on boot, the card stops working and it won't come back to life unless I temporarily disable the battery of my laptop directly from the BIOS)^[1].

According to the answer of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237822/abnormal-behavior-with-iwlwifi-driver-the-device-is-shown-as-not-working), what you see on the additional drivers is not actually a real problem.

Nonetheless, if you search for errors with `dmsg` or with `journalctl` you will find errors of this kind:

```
[   44.601884] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
```

If you check [this thread](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/intel-ax200-wifi-card-unstable-after-firmware-update/127904), this seems to be a kernel problem, which is trying to load the wrong driver.
Recent versions of the kernel (5.5+) seem to solve it, but ubuntu 20.04 is still on kernel version 5.4 and I bet it will not change until the next kernel LTS version (2021?).

I don't think this answers your question, but I really hope it does help you.

---

[1] You could call it "forced electronic reset", unplugging and re-plugging the wifi card itself works the same, but I have no idea on why I need to do it.