# Abnormal behavior with iwlwifi driver: the device is shown as not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, kubuntu, iwlwifi

Recently I've installed Kubuntu in a newly bought laptop with an Intel WiFi 6 AX200 network card, I can connect to the wifi without apparent problems but when I open the driver manager in the settings I face this weird situation:

```
Intel Corporation: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
This device is not working.
 [ ] Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from backport-iwlwifi-dkms (open source)
 [ ] Continue using a manually installed driver
 [x] Do not use the device
```

Note that "Continue using a manually installed driver" is the only voice selectable in the list.

Here is some additional information:

```bsh
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.888227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.945179] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.945217] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.947244] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.947250] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.947252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.947697] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.145585] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.159226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.160060] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.336456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 50:eb:71:d7:0b:40
[    3.353553] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.457920] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.621843] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[    4.629999] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Someone have idea why this happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is normal. Canonical used `ubuntu-drivers` utility to install `iwlwifi` backports when it is needed. That was not a perfect idea, because it confuses newbies.

The message that `device is not working` really means that backport drivers are not installed. They probably don't even exist for this release/kernel.

So, ignore this message.