# Ubuntu software and updates says my wifi adapter is not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, macbook

does it imply my wifi adapter is broken?
I have an old macBook air from 2009, I have installed on it Ubuntu 22.04. it works but very slowly. now I want to use it as a server. I want to use the wifi adapter that's built-in, but it didn't install the proper driver. so I have downloaded the driver using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv1NfRlEz8s) Youtube instructional video. Now i have come to the Ubuntu software and updates to add the driver on the Additional drivers tab, but then I saw that it says the device is not working. so I want to know if it could be the device is physically broken or it just means something with the driver isn't OK.
I have tried before this to install the driver manually using modprob <driver_name> but got the error message saying: Module does not exist in... 
I have already looked at [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108702/changed-permissions-of-to-user) and at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546363/software-updater-software-updates-not-working)  thread so I don't think there is any duplicity here. thank you in advance and sorry dor my English:)[this is a picture I have taken from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siKpP.jpg)
I looked also at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237822/abnormal-behavior-with-iwlwifi-driver-the-device-is-shown-as-not-working) article

Comment: Please start a new question about your wireless being slow. Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368031/why-arent-proprietary-drivers-in-use/1368042#1368042 where it says: "The statement that "This device not working" is simply incorrect. The Additional Drivers utility often shows the same incorrect warning." Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't understand why open a new question?

Comment: @chili555 thank you a lot. I have succeded to install the driver