# Intel AX200 Wifi works but Bluetooth doesn't

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, intel

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and have an Intel AX200 Wifi 6 (Gig+) wifi/bluetooth card. My wifi works just fine but my operating system doesn't seem to recognize that the card also supports bluetooth.

Unlike [Bluetooth/Wi-Fi Troubleshooting: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Intel AX200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233040/bluetooth-wi-fi-troubleshooting-ubuntu-20-04-lts-intel-ax200), my "Software & Updates" only shows my GPU not the wifi/bluetooth card. I have tried installing the driver for "Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz" from https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi, copying it into `/lib/firmware`, and rebooting but that didn't seem to work either.

Here is the result when I run `dmesg | grep iwl`. Let me know if you need more information!

```
[    3.480424] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.485588] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.485603] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.486825] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.486827] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.486828] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.487005] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.504740] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.516892] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.517361] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.667363] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: c8:b2:9b:e9:cd:e3
[    3.684555] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.548573] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.698841] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

Comment: iwlwifi is unrelated to bluetooth. Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: Do you have a gigabyte motherboard? https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/AX200-bluetooth-not-working/td-p/1234952

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/cant-turn-on-bluetooth-bluetooth-adapter/0d39e7be-c61c-4d11-8efb-7e15678a5ae7 and there are also a few threads on Reddit about this same hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to 20.04.1 today (Sept7,2020) a reboot rendered my wireless and bluetooth dead.  this is my error `iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110` when doing `dsmesg | grep iwl`

I downloaded the drivers from Intel directly and installed them, they didn't work. I then went to my other ubuntu 20.04 machine, that i didn't update,copied the drivers and installed them. I'm back in business.

Hopefully this can help someone else out. Here is the link to the drivers that got me up and running.

https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZUy90XZijUtNfb5PUFgeVyssnKP2HrJvbhy

I might add i have the exact same output as you except for the first and last line.

```
[2.461097] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2 
[2.461417] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2 
[2.462833] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17 
[2.462835] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[2.462835] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[2.463002] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm 
[2.488992] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340 
[2.505891] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM 
[2.506753] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor. 
[2.681561] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: base HW address: 5c:80:b6:f4:00:92
[3.050667] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0 wlp82s0: renamed from wlan0 
[5.360519] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM 
[5.529563] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring 
[5.536641] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey Xavier! I returned my GPU in anticipation of the October release of the NVIDIA RTX 3070 so I can't actually test your solution but I will once the new GPU arrives. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just an FYI, it appears something is up with the 20.04.1 update. my other box has the Intel 7260 wireless adapter and after i did the update it too died. Luckily i copied the entre /lib/firmware directory somewhere before I did. getting back onlnie was as simple as just copying the driver back then reboot.

Comment: I see... so it's not just the Intel AX 200 wifi/bluetooth card that is experiencing these issues. Thanks for the update—it's very useful!

Comment: further to this, another update broke something and the previous steps wouldn't work so i upgraded to the latest kernel 5.8.11-050811-generic. Turned it off then turned it on. Now it works, and survives a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately I'm still without a GPU so I can't test this on my machine but hopefully upgrading the kernel will do the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I had to revert back to 5.4.0-58-generic kernel. After reboot the system never connected with my mouse and keyboard again. using 5.4.0-58-generic works fine

I had the same issue after resuming the system from sleep. Wifi woorked but no vluetooth. I have re-installed ubuntu using the same image I used before, and still nothing happend. I tried different kernels and different drivers, non of them brought back the bluetooth.

Eventually clearing the CMOS helped, and bluetooth is back now. Have a look at your mobo manual how to clear CMOS. Most often it's a circuit jumper to short or removing the battery from the mobo.

I have a msi x570 tomahawk mobo with integrated wifi & bluetooth (Intel AX200).
My kernel is: 5.9.0-050900-generic
iwlwifi wersion: iwlwifi-cc-a0-46 (June/July 2019)

Comment: Is there a bug report relating to this issue? On elementary OS Hera 5.1.7 I experience the same issue: Gigabye B550i Aorus Pro AX, running kernel 5.10.11. Sometimes bluetooth disappears, as in the system believes the hardware capability isn't present. It did so yesterday. **Not even a liveusb session could bring bluetooth back.** Today it loaded again fine after a night's sleep. Is this a hardware issue? Kernel loads iwlwifi-cc-a0-59 but loads ibt-20-1-3 and not ibt-20-1-4 for bluetooth. I may try removing the older firmware temporarily to see if I can force it to load the newer.

Comment: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-firmware-install-help.73391/ Other people experiencing issues with ax200 bluetooth cutting out completely, and refusing to load the latest (ibt-20-1-4) firmware.

Comment: `modinfo btintel` lists only ibt-12-16 and ibt-11-5 as firmware versions: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/bluetooth/btintel.c Is this only metadata or does this file need to be updated to include later firmware revisions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually upgrading to the latest Ubuntu linux-firmware package? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-firmware (in this case hirsute 1.194)

Comment: Hirsute is the codename of release scheduled for public release in April 2021. The packages are still in beta stage and should not be installed on a stable release.

Comment: Sure. any more recent linux-firmware package may include driver updates that fix performance issues, at least for diagnostic purposes. Driver updates in Linux distributions tend to lag far behind mfr rollouts, so I don't think it is always reasonable to try to stick to distro version-locked drivers with newer hardware.

Comment: LTS releases generally backports some features with point releases. For example, I'm using 20.04 but due to HWE, I'm getting kernel which came with 20.10. Installing packages from a different release, even from stable ones, in worst case, may cause dependency hell. If you really need that particular firmware, how about upgrading in first place instead of messing dependency tree?

Comment: yes, I agree about dependency hell. But in this case linux-firmware doesn't have dependencies, it just installs drivers to /lib/firmware/*